# nonlinear navigation using imageviews in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I've looked at the various navigation controllers in ios and none seems able to achieve what I'm looking for in my next app.

Is there a way to bypass navigation controllers altogether and simply "jump" from one viewcontroller to another on the basis of the content shown, buttons pressed, or gestures made?

For example, if I were to graphically set up nine view controllers in a 3 x 3 grid, and place swipe gestures (up, down, left, and right) on each, and then (with wrapping) connect each to the one above, below, to the left of, and to the right of it, I could navigate from one view to another without the need for a navigation controller.

The app I'm planning will do something similar. Each view will have its own gestures/buttons/"hotspots" which will bring another view to the fore. I've seen very little anywhere (including this site) about nonhierarchical (or nonlinear) navigation among views.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation Controllers can be used in non-hierarchical fashion (as in the example you quoted) as well. In this case NavController just holds the presentedViewController as a wrapper and presents it. When done, you navigate back to the parent VC. From there you can navigate to another VC via another NavController. So for your 3x3 example, when the user swipes/gestures on one view launch  its VC wrapped in a new NavVC. When done, you navigate back to the parent 3x3 view. You repeat that for each gesture associated with each of your views in that 3x3 grid.

Comment: If I were to number the views from 1 to 9, are you saying I must go from 1 to 3 (say), then back to 1 before I go to 5 (say)? Can I not go directly from 1 to 3 then to 5?

Comment: you can use push VC#5 onto the same NavVC; and from #5 you can decide where to go back (either go back to previous one #3 or to the earlier one #1)  by popping out to the desired VC (see following in NavVC: `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers` and `popToViewController:animated:`

Comment: Many thanks! Will this work with an indefinite number of VCs?

Comment: Yes. It would. Think of NavVCs as 'browser history' in a browser, you can traverse back to any of the past VC of a given NavVC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. Navigation controllers are only one of a variety of ways to navigate between view controllers in iOS.

You can control-drag from a button to another scene in your storyboard to create a custom segue. If you select a modal segue then the system will add the new view controller as a modal on top of the current view controller.

Be aware that you can't endlessly push new view controllers. When you want to go back, you need to do a dismiss to get rid of the previous modal. Alternately you should be able to set up an unwind segue, although I've only used them once or twice and am still not rock-solid on using them.

Comment: But isn't modal 'linear', in other words, don't I eventually have to go 'back'? Suppose I want to go from view 1 to view 7 to view 3 then to view 4 and then do something altogether different, never coming 'back' to any of these?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that one can programatically instantiate and present view controllers within the same storyboard or even within other storyboards, without the use of a navigation controller. Many thanks for the above answers, but this is better suited to my need.